# How can Gröbner bases be generalized to differential algebra?

Tags: groebner-bases, differential-algebra

I'm aware of the Rosenfeld-Gröbner algorithm "for computing a regular decomposition of a radical differential ideal generated by a set of polynomial differential equations, ordinary or with partial derivatives" as it's described in [1].

Is this the best known generalization of Buchberger's algorithm to differential algebra?

Leaving any specific algorithm aside, is the representation of the ideal produced by Rosenfeld-Gröbner the best known generalization of Gröbner bases to differential algebra?

**Reference**

[1] Hashemi, A., Touraji, Z. (2014). "[An Improvement of Rosenfeld-Gröbner Algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-44199-2_70)", in: Hong, H., Yap, C. (eds) *Mathematical Software – ICMS 2014*, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 8592, Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer, [MR3334804](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR3334804),  [Zbl 1434.13001](https://zbmath.org/1434.13001).